# php write file converts single quotes to double quotes

Tags: php

My code is like this

```
$fp = fopen('text.php', 'w');
fwrite($fp, $_POST['code']);
fclose($fp);
```

But if `$_POST['code']` has single quotes (') output will be 2 single quotes
for example:

 if input is 'test'

if we open text.php 
output will

> ''test''

i also tried file_put_contents()
but same result
How can i solve this problem?

**edit**

for `$_POST['code'];` `exit()` also i am getting same output

Comment: You should be using `wb` as the mode, not `w`. Try that, see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: Thanks..i tried that but same result

Comment: This behavior doesn't happen for me on Windows 7 running PHP 5.4.15 via the embedded server.  Can you `echo $_POST['code']; exit();` before you `fwrite()` to make sure you don't have double-single-quoted input already?

Comment: echo $_POST['code']; exit(); for this code also same output so how to eliminate this?

Comment: That means what is being sent to your script already contains the double, single-quotes.  Where is `$_POST['code']` being sent from?

Comment: $_POST['code'] is send from textarea

Comment: Do you have some automatic processing of input variables like those in `$_POST`?

Comment: no!! reinstall server solved my problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try re-installing your lamp server.